# Simple Javascript front-end message board design

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, messageboard

I am working on a personal blog website project, and I wanted to implement a simple message board on my index page. Due to the projected site traffic (relatively low) I decided on only using a front-end implementation without linking to a database with the following js and html code:

```
<section class="message-board">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>
                Leave a message
            </h2>
        </div>
        <textarea class="message" type="text"></textarea><br/>
        <input value="submit" type="button" class="submit-btn">
        <div class="display-area">
            Existing comment:
        </div>
    </section>
```

and then the js,

```
<script>
          window.onload=function() {
              var displayArea = document.getElementsByClassName("display-area");
              var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("submit-btn");
              btn.onclick = function() {
                  var comment = document.getElementsByClassName("message").value;
                  displayArea.appendChild(comment);
              };
          }  
    </script>
```

My intention was to make my `display-area` contain whatever was put in `textarea` via `.appendChild` when `submit` is clicked. Sadly, it isn't working as intended-nothing actually happens. I am thinking about potential errors in my js code, but just couldn't figure out anything that would resolve the problem.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: make a template html. append the template and set innerHTML to the message. Or alternatively, instead of the template, hardcode the html into your javascript or make an external html file.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways this can be done are by calling the JavaScript function on click, or by calling it on form submission.

**1) call function onclick:**

Wrap your form within a form tag, and call your JavaScript function based on the element Ids.

Note the showInput function is being called onclick when the button is clicked.

```js
function showInput() {
  console.log('showInput called...')
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  display.innerHTML = userInput;
}
```

```html
<section class="message-board">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>
      Leave a message
    </h2>
  </div>

  <form>
    <textarea class="message" type="text" id="userInput"></textarea><br/>
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();">
  <div class="display-area">
    Existing comment:
  </div>
  <p><span id="display"></span></p>
</section>
```

Here's a jsfiddle, with the same code as above: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanryan/94kvj0sc/

Note the JavaScript in the jsfiddle is being called at the bottom of the Head section of the HTML.

**2) call function on form submit:**

You can also do this by calling the JavaScript function on the submission of the form, instead of on the click of the button. However, since this form uses a textarea, hitting return will add a line break to the text, and not submit the form, so the button still needs to be clicked for the function to be called.

```js
function showInput() {
  console.log('showInput called...')
  event.preventDefault()
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  display.innerHTML = userInput;
}
```

```html
<section class="message-board">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>
      Leave a message
    </h2>
  </div>

  <form onsubmit="showInput()">
    <textarea class="message" type="text" id="userInput"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>


  <div class="display-area">
    Existing comment:
  </div>
  <p><span id="display"></span></p>
</section>
```

Note the event.preventDefault() in the form, since the default behavior of forms is to submit data to a backend database.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanryan/qpufd469/

**3. appending instead of replacing text**

Finally, my examples above used innerHTML to replace the userInput text. If you want to append instead of replace the text, you can use insertAdjacentHTML to add the text to the end, and then append a linebreak to it. Finally, you can reset the form.

```js
function showInput() {
  console.log('showInput called...')
  event.preventDefault()
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  var theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");
  var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
  display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', userInput);
  display.appendChild(linebreak);
  theForm.reset();
}
```

```html
<section class="message-board">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>
      Leave a message
    </h2>
  </div>

  <form onsubmit="showInput()" id="theForm">
    <textarea class="message" type="text" id="userInput"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>


  <div class="display-area">
    Existing comment:
  </div>
  <p><span id="display"></span></p>
</section>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanryan/x4hq0Lzp/

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByClassName()** returns a collection of elements (note the *s* in *Elements*). If you have only one element that matches the class name, you have this element in the first index of the array-like collection.

```
var displayArea = document.getElementsByClassName("display-area")[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("submit-btn")[0];
```

You can also use **querySelector()**, that uses CSS selectors (like jQuery) and returns a single element:

```
var displayArea = document.querySelector(".display-area");
```

In order to append a text node (your variable comment stores a string), use **append()** instead of **appendChild()**:

```
displayArea.append(comment);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, not an array.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, you're right, I wanted to simplify my answer. I've edited it to reflect your correction.

Comment: That's still an over simplification (there's more to an instance of HTMLCollection than just an object representing a collection of elements), but... meh.